# How to deploy CakePHP-application on CentOS?

Tags: cakephp, centos

I almost managed to deploy a CakePHP-application on CentOS-server, but it still needs little configuration. I have enabled mod_rewrite in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and restarted apache-server.

Then I have put Cake core library in /home/user/cakephp-core/

I get message "500 internal error" when i try to go to this page through web-browser.

In apache-logs I found following messages:

```
PHP Warning:  include(/$HOME/cakephp-core/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/www/site/public_html/main/index.php on line 96
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/$HOME/cakephp-core/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/site/public_html/main/index.php on line 96
PHP Fatal error:  CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your /cake core directory and your /vendors root directory. in /srv/www/site/public_html/main/index.php on line 101
```

it says something about "permission denied"... to whom I should give permissions and where? I gave "apache:apache" to tmp/-folder... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply read the log and try to understand it.

It pretty clearly tells you what has insufficient permissions. The linux command to set permissions is *chmod*. You also want to make sure, as the text already tells you, that your CakePHP core include path is correct. Double check that too.